# How to Repair MySQL InnoDB Table That Has Issues?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqlcheck

Our company is using SailPoint IIQ for its IAM solution.

When trying to run:
`delete IdentityRequest *`

I get an error of `sailpoint.tools.GeneralException: null index column for collection: sailpoint.object.IdentityRequest.items`

Doing a `select * from spt_identity_request_item where id is null;` returns no results.

I'm reaching for straws and have attempted to repair the table, in case that is what is causing the issue. The table types they use for their db is innodb.

`repair table spt_identity_request_item;` yields a note of `The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair`

I've also tried the command:

`sudo mysqlcheck --repair --databases identityiq -u identityiq -p`

While it runs, it gives a bunch of notes of:

`note     : The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair`

Is this command actually doing something to repair the issues? If not, is there a way to repair this and how?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the above is using an ORM to do a delete operation, and is erring not in sql, but on the application-level:

```
sailpoint.tools.GeneralException: 
    null index column for collection: sailpoint.object.IdentityRequest.items
```

In other words, it's probably failing before it even gets to the SQL level and so doing a `repair table` would have no consequence. Perhaps you need to specify how to handle the deletions of the M2M table in `sailpoint.object.IdentityRequest.items`. For example, my guess is that it doesn't know whether to NULLify or DELETE the objects that are being referenced in the FK relations.